# Starting Celery: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I try to start a Celery worker server from a command line:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

The code in tasks.py:

```
import os
os.environ[ 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' ] = "proj.settings"

from celery import task

@task()
def add_photos_task( lad_id ):
...
```

I get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.0.12', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 946, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/celery.py", line 890, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 177, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 295, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/celery/bin/base.py", line 313, in find_app
    return sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

Does anybody know why the 'celery' attribute cannot be found? Thank you for help.

The operating system is Linux Debian 5.

**Edit**. May be the clue. Could anyone explain me the next comment to a function (why we must be sure that it finds modules in the current directory)?

```
# from celery/utils/imports.py
def import_from_cwd(module, imp=None, package=None):
    """Import module, but make sure it finds modules
    located in the current directory.

    Modules located in the current directory has
    precedence over modules located in `sys.path`.
    """
    if imp is None:
        imp = importlib.import_module
    with cwd_in_path():
        return imp(module, package=package)
```

Comment: Are you not using `djcelery`?

Comment: @patrys Both the packages 'celery' and 'django-celery' are installed. Do I understand your question?

Comment: If you have Django bindings installed, why not use `$ ./manage.py celeryd` instead?

Comment: @patrys It's convenient to check the functionality from a command line (while I'm setting up a server). I want to see some output in a console window.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I forgot to create a celery object in tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import task  

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//') #!

import os

os.environ[ 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' ] = "proj.settings"

@task()
def add_photos_task( lad_id ):
...
```

After that we could normally start tasks:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 21):

For anyone who is getting the same error message for an apparently different reason, note that if any of the imports in your initialization file fail, your app will raise this totally ambiguous `AttributeError` rather than the exception that initially caused it.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I get this when I've accidentally got imports that become circular, so that is something to watch for.

Comment: thank you! I was using an undeclared variable inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` because I missspelled it. I was getting crazy looking at my project directories because the problem was not there! neither in celeryconfig!

Answer (score 12):

Celery uses `celery` file for storing configuration of your app, you can't just give a python file with tasks and start celery.
You should define `celery` file ( for Celery>3.0; previously it was `celeryconfig.py`)..

> celeryd --app app.celery -l info

This example how to start celery with config file at `app/celery.py`

Here is example of celery file: https://github.com/Kami/libcloud-sandbox/blob/master/celeryconfig.py

Comment: Thank you. But I do this on Windows, it works normally. I have not a special configuration file. Do I understand the Celery docs correctly (could you take a look please?): http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#running-the-celery-worker-server

Comment: Where you store you broker settings and etc.

Comment: Yes, if you change it according to my.

Comment: What did you actually forgot to do?

I have similar problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007101/starting-celery-with-supervisord-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribu)

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I put the `celery` variable inside a main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  # Remove this row
    app = Flask(__name__)
    celery = make_celery(app)
```

when it should be put outside.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`, your celery app should be exposed in the module `tasks`. It shouldn't be wrapped in a function or an `if` statements that.

If you `make_celery` in another file, you should import the celery app in to your the file you are passing to celery.

Answer (score 1):

Try start celery:

`celeryd --config=my_app.my_config --loglevel=INFO --purge -Q my_queue`

There is next script in my `tasks.py`:

```
@task(name="my_queue", routing_key="my_queue")
def add_photos_task( lad_id ):
```

There is next script in `my_config.py`:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = \
(
    "my_app.tasks",
)
CELERY_ROUTES = \
{
    "my_queue":
    {
        "queue": "my_queue"
    },
}
CELERY_QUEUES = \
{
    "my_queue":
    {
        "exchange": "my_app",
        "exchange_type": "direct",
        "binding_key": "my_queue"
    },
}
celery = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
```