# Starting Celery with supervisord: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: celery, daemon, supervisord, attributeerror

I used to have all my Flask app code and celery code in one file and it worked fine with supervisor.  However, it is very hair so I split my tasks to celery_tasks.py and this problem occurs.

In my project directory, I can start celery manually with the following command

```
celery -A celery_tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

However, because this is a server, I need celery to run as a daemon in background.
But it shows following error when I called `sudo supervisorctl restart celeryd`

```
celeryd: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

and the log said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.0.19', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    main()
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 957, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 901, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 185, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 300, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/srv/www/learningapi.stanford.edu/peerAPI/peerAPIenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 318, in find_app
    return sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

I used the following config.

```
[program:celeryd]
command = celery -A celery_tasks worker --loglevel=INFO

user=peerapi
numprocs=4

stdout_logfile = <path to log>
stderr_logfile = <path to log>
autostart = true
autorestart = true
environment=PATH="<path to my project>"

startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

My code also init celery properly

```
celery = Celery('celery_tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
                backend='amqp')
celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

and my celeryconfig.py is working normally

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE='America/Los Angeles'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True
```

Any clue?

Comment: Have you looked here: [Running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application can't find your celeryconfig, it happens because you CWD is not set for example. Try to use something like:
  cd app_path; celeryd ...
Also you need to setup env

```
# local settings
PATH=/home/ubuntu/envs/app/bin:$PATH
PYTHONHOME=/home/ubuntu/envs/app/
PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/projects/app/
```

Should work.